# Azure isMemberOf api gives "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." error when trying to access from Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: rest, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-ad-graph-api

So my requirement is for the application running on Azure Machine to check if a particular Azure user logged in belongs to an assigned Azure group.

I have enabled Managed Service Identity for the said virtual machine.
[MSI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqLqf.png)

I get the token for the VM by making a call to the metadata service running locally using the following command for the graph resource on the VM:

```
curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net' -H Metadata:true
```

Once I get the token I make a POST request to the graph API of [isMemberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/graphrbac/groups/ismemberof) with that newly acquired token:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <token-value>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"groupId":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","memberId":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}' https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/isMemberOf?api-version=1.6
```

I get the following response

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

I have assigned the resource group the VM belongs to with IAM as a owner to the resource

Am I missing something that I should have it configured or I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I dug around a little bit and found that Microsoft prefers us developers using Microsoft Graph rather than the Azure AD Graph
[Microsoft Graph vs Azure AD Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)

I found a similar call in Microsoft Graph API to get member of information [User list member of call](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof)
This call requires the following [scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjzBX.png):

```
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

And these are the steps I followed:

1. Application would need to fetch the token for making the Microsoft graph API call.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

HEADER
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

BODY:
client_id=&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 0,
    "access_token": "<token-value>"
}
```

Client secret is generated at app registration time.

2. Application would make the call to microsoft graph API to fetch

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-object-id}/checkMemberGroups

HEADERS:    Authorization: Bearer {token-value}
            Content-Type: application/json

BODY:

```
{
    "groupIds":["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
}
```

RESPONSE:

200 OK - if user belongs to the group

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(Edm.String)",
    "value": [
        "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]
}
```

404 Not found - if user does not exist

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "date": "2018-05-23T02:54:47"
        }
    }
}
```

This would help application identify if the Azure user belongs to the assigned group or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Azure AD Graph API, not ARM API.
The IAM blade only gives access rights for the ARM API.

You'll need to assign the necessary rights to the service principal kinda manually.

I actually wrote an article on this a while back: [Calling your APIs with Azure AD Managed Service Identity using application permissions](https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions).

You will need:

1. Your MSI service principal object id (you can see how to find this in my article)
2. The target service principal object id (in this case Azure AD Graph API)
3. Id of the app permission you want to assign (you can use e.g. https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net to find these, they are under appRoles on the service principal)

Once you have these, then you can run this PowerShell cmdlet (using the AAD v2 cmdlets):

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId msi-sp-id -Id app-permission-id -PrincipalId msi-sp-id -ResourceId aad-graph-sp-id
```

Then everything should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @juunas. I followed the steps to make the following call
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <token-value>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"id":"xxx","principalId":"xxx","resourceId":"xxx"}' https://graph.windows.net/xxx/servicePrincipals/xxx/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
id = app role id assigned by editing the metadata
principalID = object id got from the VM which hosts the application
resourceID = object id of the app registration. But i get Access token missing or malformed.

Comment: Also when i try the power shell command New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment, I get a message saying that command does not exist.

Comment: You need the cmdlets installed: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.1.10